# Yiii - index file

Tags: yii

I want to analyze the code of Yii framework...but I can't find the index file :E Where is it, and how does the server know what to search for, if .htaccess doesn't contain any specific rules?

Comment: Yiii = yet it is index ?

Comment: Isn't index.php the default server's file?

Answer (score 1):

You first have to setup the framework (in the command prompt).
[Here is a fairly straight forward guide](http://yiitutorials.net/easy/step-by-step-guide-setup-the-yii-framework) as to getting this done and [here is a guide from the Yii website](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app).

Once the framework is setup you will have an index.php file

Answer (score 1):

Yii is a framework, not website. To see basic webapp create it (watch [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app) from @eskimo)

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`in linux terminal type

> $ sudo /path/to/yii/framework/yiic webapp /var/www/installationfolder

or simply read README

on installed folder you will find index.php

here is the code anyways

```
<?php   

// change the following paths if necessary


 $yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../yii/framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';

// remove the following lines when in production model

 defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);

// specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message


 defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);

require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();

?>
```